# Communication between two sessions with example

Tags: c#, asp.net

In an asp.net application there are two different users are available.

When user is entered we store UserId of the user in session variable.

When First user sends requests to the server than server give response to first user.

But My question is If First user sends request then server sends request to second user like an communication between first and second user.

How it is possible in Asp.net?

Comment: you also asked the same question in a different way few minutes before http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8768084/communication-between-to-sessions-wih-example/8768245#8768245  you can edit your that question also,need not to create a new one again.

Answer (score 0):

you cant use the session object you should use the Cache object or the Application Object.

Comment: If your IIS is speedy/Fast then use Cache or Application OR when first user send request at that time store the data in DB and after getting the data , remove from DB.